# meta doesn't confirm my request to google openid

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, openid

I wanted to test openid but when logging out, it automatically log me in when I ask to authenticate through openid without asking me to confirm with Google.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if you selected "remember my selection" (or something similar) when you first authenticated with Google on this site.

Comment: I have loggout of Google that's why I ask.

Answer (score 1):

Read in more detail about how openid (and google's implementation of it) work in particular:

[Why am I stilled logged into Gmail *AND* StackOverflow after logging out of StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41094/why-am-i-stilled-logged-into-gmail-and-stackoverflow-after-logging-out-of-stack/41098#41098)

In short, logging into openID puts a cookie on your computer, generally for a day, that makes it so you don't have to log into your openid again that day.  It has nothing to do with SO.  SO still goes and asks your OpenID provider if you're legit, they look at the cookie, and say, "meh, he's ok, I guess.  He logged on once today so I'm not going to make him do it again," and SO logs you back on because your provider said you were an ok kind of guy after all.