# Problem with logging out

Tags: support, logout

Every time I log in from a shared computer on Stack Overflow, I am not able to log out.

Even if I click log out, it takes me to the home page and when I click the login link it automatically logs me back in. I neither allow my browser to save passwords or nor to remember me.

I get this message each time

> Welcome back user. Click here to refresh the page

Each time I have to clear all my cookies from my browser to log out from it. Why does this happen?

Comment: Basically, OpenID is hard to get your head around.

Comment: @michaelb958 Even i tried to log out from stackexchange but still i am logged in every time

Comment: What type of account do you use to log into Stack Exchange? (Possibly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41094/why-doesnt-logging-out-of-stack-overflow-log-me-out-of-gmail)

Comment: @DuncanJones first i use to login with gmail, then when i linked my account with stackexchange, Now i login with stack exchange automatically

Comment: I also took a video for the whole scenario whats happening

Comment: Did you log out from https://openid.stackexchange.com/ ? Did you log out of google? Log out from both, then log out from your account. If that still doesn't work, clear the cookies then log out.

Comment: @oded i have already logged out from both. Thats what i mentioned, to log out i have to clear my cookies always manually

Comment: Related: *[Tell me how to log out of Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)*

Answer (score 5):

If you click Log out on the page that looks similar to this one:

[image]

You'll notice the text at the bottom:

> If you're on a shared computer, remember to log out of your Open ID provider (Facebook, Google, Stack Exchange OpenID, etc.) as well.

Clicking Logout only logs you out from the Stack Exchange sites but **NOT** from the Stack Exchange OpenID provider. That behavior is similar to what you get when using Google or Facebook. You don't expect Stack Exchange to log you out from Gmail or from the facebook timeline you're watching.

To get to your Stack Exchange OpenID page isn't that obvious though.
Its direct url is https://openid.stackexchange.com/

To get to it from the UI follow these steps. First go to My Logins, for example in your Network profile:

[image: click for larger version]

Now click change password (trust me, you're not going to change your password). After clicking you'll be on your OpenID profile page:

[image: click for larger version]

Now you can click on the Logout tab which will bring you to the actual logout page of the Stack Exchange OpenID provider:

[image: click for larger version]

You can click the Log Out button here. That will log you out from the OpenID provider.

After clicking that button you'll notice that you have to re-enter all your credentials if you want to login again in any of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: That is a remarkably labyrinthine process. +1 for detailed instructions, though.

Answer (score 3):

You are logged into two separate things:

1. the stack overflow site
2. the openid provider

If you log out of #1 and then attempt to log in again using the same provider, it will instantly log you back into the same account beacuse you are still logged into #2.

To log out of #2, if you use the StackExchange OpenId provider, you have to visit this URL :    https://openid.stackexchange.com/   Once there, you can log out of the provider.

In both cases, logout is a two step function (unlike most sites).  You first click a "logout" link to get to the logout page.  Then, on that page, you have to click a Logout buttton.  This is poor usability (this tripped me up twice) and should be clearer.

More important is the login for #1 should have a "logout from the provider" link on it so that you can at that point logout of #2.  I have seen some openid implementations start to do this.  Every provider might have a different logout address.

Answer (score 1):

When you are click log out option on Stack Overflow than show log out page and click logout than not proper logout your account in 'Mozilla firefox' but 'crome browser' not show this problem.

**Mozilla**

sign up  **log in**  careers 2.0

Again log in option click than permanently logout your a/c and not login a/c after page refresh.