# Logs in automatically after logout

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, user-accounts, logout

I just registered an account at Stack Exchange.com. So far I only joined two network sites (meta, and cross validated). I somehow understand how the login system works for the network sites. What I don't get is why I get automatically logged in although I explicitly logged out of all sites.

It goes like this: I log out explicitly of any site and of Stack Exchange.com. When I now click on 'log in' at Stack Exchange.com and choose 'log in with Stack Exchange account' it automatically logs in without asking for my password. The only thing I can do is to delete my browser history.

I find this very troublesome, since this makes using a shared or public computer (which I do from time to time) very unsafe.

Does anyone know what's up with this?

Comment: related [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118247/stack-exchange-openid-credentials-not-removed-on-logout-allowing-insecure-re-lo) but I have to see if the new login changed anything/much about this issue.

Comment: Thanks @rene. It seems to be the same problem. Is my stackexchange account and OpenID the same thing? The post is four years old and they do not offer a solution other than 'clear your browser history'. But this cannot possibly be a concept for logging out. Let me restate my question: How can I conveniently logout from stackexchange and related sites possible subsites such that I am really logged out and not some user who uses the brower afterwards can log in without giving credentials? (Without clearing browser history, of course...how weird is that?!)

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207024/152859) is what you need. Assuming you have Stack Exchange account, you have to visit https://openid.stackexchange.com/ and log out in there. Then clicking login will require a password. If you're using other provider,e.g. Google, you will have to do the same, i.e. log out from the provider itself.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard for closing. Now I had to post my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273441/158100) ;)

Comment: @rene my pleasure! Your answer is better than the old one, cheers!

Comment: @ShadowWizard and rene, thanks for the help...now I get it -.-  But think it is totally not clear what to do to log out. But once you know, it's OK

Comment: Yeah, that's what we have Meta for. :)