# How to investigate Stack Overflow account hacking that resulted in answering some question inappropriately?

Tags: discussion, login, hacked

About an hour ago, from my account, an inappropriate message was posted as a reply to a Stack Overflow question.

I have noticed it, because I started getting downvotes. To my understanding my Gmail account wasn't compromised (I reviewed my account security settings and login history). I am from a secure WPA2 connection. I cannot find enough information on how to investigate this. Although I changed my passwords everywhere, I still seem confused and I would like to ask how to investigate this issue myself.

Comment: Do you have a link to this question?

Comment: @Shog9 http://stackoverflow.com/a/20175825

Comment: Exactly! Thank you @animuson.

Comment: Is it possible that your account wasn't hacked? Maybe someone accessed your computer while you were away from it.. I never log out of my account, so this could be true for me anyways... though i'm never away from my computer anyways..

Comment: Highly unlikely (however if I knew the IP of "my" answer, I could investigate it further).

Comment: It's a forthnet IP; guessing you don't want the specific address made public, but if you'd like to contact us privately (link at the bottom of the page) I can pass that on.

Comment: @JoshC this means (maybe) that this isn't a bot or something auto generated (or else I am patient zero).

Comment: @Shog9, yes I have already contacted you through the contact us form. Thank you, by the way!

Comment: @Shog9 can you send my the ip in my email? I have contacted you through the contact form.

Comment: I've replied to your email.

Comment: I removed the message. It didn't matter after all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

1. Make sure friends or co-workers aren't inadvertently posting as you. We hear about this a lot when folks are using shared computers and [forget to log out *everwhere*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41094/why-doesnt-logging-out-of-stack-overflow-log-me-out-of-gmail) when they're done.
2. Talk to your network admin. No one *should* ever be deploying their own root CA to your machine, intercepting HTTPS traffic and then sending you the wrong pages... [But that doesn't mean they aren't](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63304/how-can-my-employer-be-a-man-in-the-middle-when-i-connect-to-gmail). We've had some reports of pretty weird stuff happening as a result of these sorts of setups.
3. Double-check [your logins](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) - make sure no one else's are in there. Occasionally, folks end up inadvertently merging their accounts with friends or co-workers (see #1).
4. Make sure no one has stolen access to your account. You've already done this, it sounds like.
5. [Contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). There's not necessarily anything we can do about it, but we can check the logs and make sure there's not something evil happening that you should be aware of.

Oh yeah - and log out everywhere. You already did this, but I'm including this for future reference, since it'll invalidate the login cookies if someone else managed to end up with them somehow.